# How to use Bash to grep, excluding some patterns, and including others?

Tags: bash, grep, find

In the file *find.out* I want to grep and find lines that have *'FinancePlus', 'Sungard' and 'Pentamation'* and I want to exclude lines containing *'PROPRIETARY, 'CONFIDENTIAL', 'Public'*

I can get the part that includes *'FinancePlus', 'Sungard' and 'Pentamation'* to work, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to exclude lines with *'PROPRIETARY, 'CONFIDENTIAL', 'Public'*

This worked for the includes:

```
grep -i -e 'FinancePlus' -e 'Sungard' -e 'Pentamation' -e 'efp' `cat find.out` > grep.txt
```

I tried this, but the exclude doesn't work:

```
grep -i -e 'FinancePlus' -e 'Sungard' -e 'Pentamation' -e 'efp' `cat find.out` > grep.txt | grep -v 'proprietary'
```

Comment: why are you using `cat find.out` ?

Comment: What is `efp` in your code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output to demonstrate your needs and so we have something we can copy/paste to test a potential solution against.

Comment: Regarding `\`cat find.out\``: do yourself a favor and learn about [`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html).

Comment: you state that  you want to ignore lines with `PROPRIETARY` (ALL CAPS) while your code says `grep -v 'proprietary'` (all lowercase); either provide an ALL CAPS arg to `grep` or if you want to exclude regardless of capitalization then use `-i` to indicate case insensitivity, eg, `grep -iv 'proprietary'`

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E '(FinancePlus|Sungard|Pentamation)' find.out |
grep -vE '(PROPRIETARY|CONFIDENTIAL|Public)'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried this, but the exclude doesn't work:
>
> ```
> grep -i -e 'FinancePlus' -e 'Sungard' -e 'Pentamation' -e 'efp' `cat find.out` > grep.txt | grep -v 'proprietary'
> ```

Of course not. You're redirecting the output of the first `grep` to output file `grep.txt`.  Nothing makes it through to the second `grep` for it to filter, and you're not doing anything with the output of that `grep` anyway.  Moving the redirection from the first `grep` to the second will get the right output captured.  I would go for a larger rewrite myself, but about the smallest change to your example that will accomplish what you seem to want would be:

```
grep -i -e 'FinancePlus' -e 'Sungard' -e 'Pentamation' -e 'efp' `cat find.out` |
  grep -v 'proprietary' > grep.txt
```

(The command was split across two lines for clarity in this medium.  That split is not semantically significant -- the shell will accept it whether you can join the lines back together or not.)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass files containing the inclusion/exclusion keywords to `grep` using the `-f` flag for a solution that scales better than passing the keywords directly.

#### Given a file `find.out` with the following contents:

```bash
$ cat find.out
```

> This is an example FinancePlus
> Sometimes all you need is a good Sungard
> Pentamation is a funny sounding word, but beware: it's most certainly PROPRIETARY
> Here's a FinancePlus, Sungard, and even a Pentamation!
> Now this is CONFIDENTIAL, so no leaking to the general Public
> Because loose lips sink ships
> This is a dummy line that will almost certainly be excluded
> only omitted with case insensitive exclusion matches (proprietary), because Sungard.

#### And two files containing the keywords:

```bash
$ cat include.txt
```

> FinancePlus
> Sungard
> Pentamation

```bash
$ cat exclude.txt
```

> PROPRIETARY
> CONFIDENTIAL
> Public

#### Then you could do use grep like so:

For a case-sensitive pattern-match:

```bash
$ cat find.out | grep -f include.txt | grep -v -f exclude.txt
```

> This is an example FinancePlus
> Sometimes all you need is a good Sungard
> Here's a FinancePlus, Sungard, and even a Pentamation!
> only omitted with case insensitive exclusion matches (proprietary), because Sungard.

For a case-insensitive pattern-match:

```bash
$ cat find.out | grep -i -f include.txt | grep -iv -f exclude.txt
```

> This is an example FinancePlus
> Sometimes all you need is a good Sungard
> Here's a FinancePlus, Sungard, and even a Pentamation!

---

This way if you want to include/exclude more keywords you can just update the `include.txt`/`exclude.txt` lists respectively and the bash command stays the same.

Comment: do I just put > grep.txt at the end to get the output in the file?

Comment: Don't be afraid to try it out yourself, you'll learn the most through experimenting with bash in the terminal :) (yeah that'll redirect the output to grep.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- You want to grep lines which include *any* of `FinancePlus`, `Sungard`,
  `Pentamation` *or* `efp`.
- But you want to exclude lines which include *any* of `PROPRIETARY`,
  `CONFIDENTIAL` *or* `Public`. The exclusion overrides the previous rule.
- All matches are case-insensitive.
- You want to redirect the result to a file `grep.txt`.

Then would you please try:

```
grep -iwve 'PROPRIETARY' -iwve 'CONFIDENTIAL' -iwve 'Public' find.out | grep -ie 'FinancePlus' -ie 'Sungard' -ie 'Pentamation' -ie 'efp' > grep.txt
```

In a shorter way:

```
grep -iwvE 'PROPRIETARY|CONFIDENTIAL|Public' find.out | grep -iE 'FinancePlus|Sungard|Pentamation|efp' > grep.txt
```